# CanActivate Observable<boolean> not working or EventEmitter.asObservable()? Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing

I'm using Observable and EventEmitter you can see the full code at: http://plnkr.co/edit/HV2sWd?p=preview

Even using publishReplay it does not work :(

I suspect of the EventEmitter.asObservable()

What I'm missing?

**auth-service.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private _isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  private _isLoggedInEvent: EventEmitter<boolean>;
  private _isLoggedInObservable: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(){
    this._isLoggedInEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    this._isLoggedInObservable =  this._isLoggedInEvent.asObservable().publishReplay(1);
    this._isLoggedInEvent.emit(false);
  }

  login() {
    return Observable.of(true).delay(1000).do(val =>{ 
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.isLoggedInEvent.emit(true);
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }

  isLoggedInObservable() : Observable<boolean> {
     return this._isLoggedInObservable;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your plunker code seems to not be working enough to test the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used BehaviorSubject in stead of event emitter and works
Here is the solution http://plnkr.co/edit/HgwGh8?p=preview

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private _isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  private _isLoggedInEvent: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  private _isLoggedInObservable: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(){
    this._isLoggedInEvent = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    this._isLoggedInObservable =  this._isLoggedInEvent.asObservable();
    //this._isLoggedInEvent.next(false);
  }

  login() {
    return Observable.of(true).delay(1000).do(val =>{ 
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.isLoggedInEvent.next(true);
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }

  isLoggedInObservable() : Observable<boolean> {
     return this._isLoggedInObservable;
  }
}
```

Comment: `EventEmitter` is not supposed to be used for anything than `@Output()`s in components and directives anyway.